# AS3 Relative points

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

So I have a Crosshair on the Stage and I have an Enemy with nested child limbs, when the below function is called I want to create a hit mark and attach it as a child to the Enemies Limb but how do I translate the X/Y position of the Crosshair to the Enemies Limb bearing in mind the Limb may also be rotated? Any help appreciated.

```
function _hit (e):void
{
    if (theEnemy.limb1.hitTestObject(crosshair)) {
        var theHit:HitMark = new HitMark();
        theHit.x = ?;
        theHit.y = ?;       
        theEnemy.limb1.addChild(theHit);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mouse coordinates inside display objects will be rotated and translated for you, assuming your crosshair follows the mouse you can do this:

```
var theHit:HitMark = new HitMark();
theHit.x = theEnemy.limb1.mouseX;
theHit.y = theEnemy.limb1.mouseY;
theEnemy.limb1.addChild(theHit);
```

If not, you'll have to use [globalToLocal()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#globalToLocal%28%29)

```
var theHit:HitMark = new HitMark();
var globalHitPoint:Point = new Point(crosshair.x, crosshair.y);
var localHitPoint:Point = theEnemy.limb1.globalToLocal(globalHitPoint);
theHit.x = localHitPoint.x;
theHit.y = localHitPoint.y;
theEnemy.limb1.addChild(theHit);
```

Comment: Hi will give the globalToLocal a go thanks for the info, the Crosshair is moved by a controller so it does not follow mouseX.

Comment: Seem this runs into problems if I use scaleX. For instance if all the Enemies are contained within View and I do View.scaleX = 0.75 the hit marks are not appearing where they should be. mmm.